# why curl didn't post my header

Tags: linux, curl, header

i get something to do with my works. but i get a problem.
i post a xml format data to the server which is a webservice interface.

here is my code:

```
curl --data @feeqry.xml -H "SOAPAction: " -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -v http://myservice-interface
```

but server return like this:
 no SOAPAction header!

so i check the data post, no SOAPAction header is sent. but Content-Type header is in the list, so, is there something wrong with my code. header "SOAPAction " don't have to fill with values, i did this in python,and loadrunner script, it works well.
in python, i define header like this:

```
h = {'SOAPAction':'', 'Content-Type':'text/xml'}
```

in loadrunner script, i add header like this:

```
web_add_header("SOAPAction","\"\"");
```

both works well.. so do help me about the question. thank you all very much.

ps: forgive my poor English.

post information :

```
About to connect() to my server port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying my server...
* Connected to my server (my server) port 8888 (#0)
> POST /my interface path HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: my server:8888
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/xml
> Content-Length: 1299
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 12:09:20 GMT
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: zh-CN
```

Answer (score 0):

i get the solution in the site: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H
Remove an internal header by giving a replacement without content on the right side of the colon, as in: -H "Host:". If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated with a semicolon, such as -H "X-Custom-Header;" to send "X-Custom-Header:".